# Python vectorizing nested for loops

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

I'd appreciate some help in finding and understanding a pythonic way to optimize the following array manipulations in nested for loops:

```
def _func(a, b, radius):
    "Return 0 if a>b, otherwise return 1"
    if distance.euclidean(a, b) < radius:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def _make_mask(volume, roi, radius):
    mask = numpy.zeros(volume.shape)
    for x in range(volume.shape[0]):
        for y in range(volume.shape[1]):
            for z in range(volume.shape[2]):
                mask[x, y, z] = _func((x, y, z), roi, radius)
    return mask
```

Where `volume.shape` (182, 218, 200) and `roi.shape` (3,) are both `ndarray` types; and `radius` is an `int`

Comment: Did any of these answers help? Relevant page to read: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: please excuse the necropost, but A: you should accept @Divakar's post.. It's a wonderful demonstration of vectorizing with numpy, and B: you should take a look at KD trees and the ball point algorithm from [`scipy.spatial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point). It is a generalizable method for your specific problem when the data is sparse or not on a regular grid. Although it's not the best method for this exact question, It's a very good thing to know about (I recently used it myself)

Comment: @Divakar your explanation was very helpful, thanks. I upvoted initially, but just recently realized purpose of the checkmark. It's done.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
m,n,r = volume.shape
x,y,z = np.mgrid[0:m,0:n,0:r]
X = x - roi[0]
Y = y - roi[1]
Z = z - roi[2]
mask = X**2 + Y**2 + Z**2 < radius**2
```

Possible improvement : We can probably speedup the last step with `numexpr` module -

```
import numexpr as ne

mask = ne.evaluate('X**2 + Y**2 + Z**2 < radius**2')
```

**Approach #2**

We can also gradually build the three ranges corresponding to the shape parameters and perform the subtraction against the three elements of `roi` on the fly without actually creating the meshes as done earlier with `np.mgrid`. This would be benefited by the use of [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for efficiency purposes. The implementation would look like this -

```
m,n,r = volume.shape
vals = ((np.arange(m)-roi[0])**2)[:,None,None] + \
       ((np.arange(n)-roi[1])**2)[:,None] + ((np.arange(r)-roi[2])**2)
mask = vals < radius**2
```

Simplified version : Thanks to @Bi Rico for suggesting an improvement here as we can use `np.ogrid` to perform those operations in a bit more concise manner, like so -

```
m,n,r = volume.shape    
x,y,z = np.ogrid[0:m,0:n,0:r]-roi
mask = (x**2+y**2+z**2) < radius**2
```

---

**Runtime test**

Function definitions -

```
def vectorized_app1(volume, roi, radius):
    m,n,r = volume.shape
    x,y,z = np.mgrid[0:m,0:n,0:r]
    X = x - roi[0]
    Y = y - roi[1]
    Z = z - roi[2]
    return X**2 + Y**2 + Z**2 < radius**2

def vectorized_app1_improved(volume, roi, radius):
    m,n,r = volume.shape
    x,y,z = np.mgrid[0:m,0:n,0:r]
    X = x - roi[0]
    Y = y - roi[1]
    Z = z - roi[2]
    return ne.evaluate('X**2 + Y**2 + Z**2 < radius**2')

def vectorized_app2(volume, roi, radius):
    m,n,r = volume.shape
    vals = ((np.arange(m)-roi[0])**2)[:,None,None] + \
           ((np.arange(n)-roi[1])**2)[:,None] + ((np.arange(r)-roi[2])**2)
    return vals < radius**2

def vectorized_app2_simplified(volume, roi, radius):
    m,n,r = volume.shape    
    x,y,z = np.ogrid[0:m,0:n,0:r]-roi
    return (x**2+y**2+z**2) < radius**2
```

Timings -

```
In [106]: # Setup input arrays  
     ...: volume = np.random.rand(90,110,100) # Half of original input sizes 
     ...: roi = np.random.rand(3)
     ...: radius = 3.4
     ...: 

In [107]: %timeit _make_mask(volume, roi, radius)
1 loops, best of 3: 41.4 s per loop

In [108]: %timeit vectorized_app1(volume, roi, radius)
10 loops, best of 3: 62.3 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit vectorized_app1_improved(volume, roi, radius)
10 loops, best of 3: 47 ms per loop

In [110]: %timeit vectorized_app2(volume, roi, radius)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.26 ms per loop

In [139]: %timeit vectorized_app2_simplified(volume, roi, radius)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.36 ms per loop
```

So, as always `broadcasting` showing its magic for a crazy almost **`10,000x`** speedup over the original code and more than **`10x`** better than creating meshes by using on-the-fly broadcasted operations!

Comment: Approach #2 is a lot like approach one with np.ogrid replacing np.mgrid.

Comment: Can we get a timing of 'app1' with `ogrid` instead of `mgrid` :).

Comment: @BiRico Why instead, when we can get everything :) Thanks a lot for the improvement there, looks much cleaner now!

Answer (score 7):

Say you first build an `xyzy` array:

```
import itertools

xyz = [np.array(p) for p in itertools.product(range(volume.shape[0]), range(volume.shape[1]), range(volume.shape[2]))]
```

Now, using [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html),

```
np.linalg.norm(xyz - roi, axis=1) < radius
```

checks whether the distance for each tuple from `roi` is smaller than radius.

Finally, just `reshape` the result to the dimensions you need.