# Rigid transformation - Python - speedup

Tags: python, performance, numpy, rigid-bodies

I have following question about faster way to compute rigid transformation (yes, I know I can simply use library but need to code this by myself).

I need to compute x' and y' for every x,y in given image. My main bottleneck is dot product for all coordinates (interpolation after this is not a problem). Currently I implemented three options:

1. list comprehension

   ```
   result = np.array([[np.dot(matrix, np.array([x, y, 1])) for x in xs] for y in ys])
   ```
2. simple double-`for` loop

   ```
   result = np.zeros((Y, X, 3))
   for x in xs:
       for y in ys:
           result[y, x, :] = np.dot(matrix, np.array([x, y, 1]))
   ```
3. np.ndenumerate

   ```
   result = np.zeros((Y, X, 3))
   for (y, x), value in np.ndenumerate(image):
       result[y, x, :] = np.dot(matrix, np.array([x, y, 1]))
   ```

The fastest way in 512x512 images is list comprehension (about 1.5x faster than `np.ndenumerate` and 1.1x faster than double for loop).

Is there any way to do this faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667342/3293881), the idea of creating `1D` arrays instead of the `2D` or `3D` meshes and using them with on-the-fly [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) operations for memory efficiency and thus achieve performance benefits, here's an approach -

```
out = ys[:,None,None]*matrix[:,1] + xs[:,None]*matrix[:,0] + matrix[:,2]
```

If you are covering all indices with `xs` and `ys` for the `512x512` sized images, we would have them created with `np.arange`, like so -

```
ys = np.arange(512)
xs = np.arange(512)
```

**Runtime test**

Function definitions -

```
def original_listcomp_app(matrix, X, Y): # Original soln with list-compr. 
    ys = np.arange(Y)
    xs = np.arange(X)
    out = np.array([[np.dot(matrix, np.array([x, y, 1])) for x in xs] \
                                                           for y in ys])
    return out    

def indices_app(matrix, X, Y):        # @Eric's soln  
    coords_ext = np.empty((Y, X, 3))
    coords_ext[...,[1,0]] = np.rollaxis(np.indices((Y, X)), 0, start=3)
    coords_ext[...,2] = 1    
    result = np.matmul(coords_ext,matrix.T)
    return result

def broadcasting_app(matrix, X, Y):  # Broadcasting based
    ys = np.arange(Y)
    xs = np.arange(X)
    out = ys[:,None,None]*matrix[:,1] + xs[:,None]*matrix[:,0] + matrix[:,2]
    return out
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [242]: # Inputs
     ...: matrix = np.random.rand(3,3)
     ...: X,Y = 512, 512
     ...: 

In [243]: out0 = original_listcomp_app(matrix, X, Y)
     ...: out1 = indices_app(matrix, X, Y)
     ...: out2 = broadcasting_app(matrix, X, Y)
     ...: 

In [244]: np.allclose(out0, out1)
Out[244]: True

In [245]: np.allclose(out0, out2)
Out[245]: True

In [253]: %timeit original_listcomp_app(matrix, X, Y)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop

In [254]: %timeit indices_app(matrix, X, Y)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

In [255]: %timeit broadcasting_app(matrix, X, Y)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.64 ms per loop
```

Comment: Good spot that this could be done with broadcasting. I'd often write `xs[None,:,None]` here for consistency with `ys[:,None,None]`, even if it is unecessary. Glad my solution proved to be at least faster than the list comp - thanks for profiling!

Comment: Thank you, both solutions work sufficiently fast - it's even faster than scikit-image built-in transformation (but still a bit slower than scipy).

Comment: @Nefarin Wow, didn't know Scipy has something to do this task. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.indices` and `np.rollaxis` to generate a 3D array, where `coords[i, j] == [i, j]`. Here the coordinates need switching

Then all you do is append the `1` you ask for, and use `@`

```
coords_ext = np.empty((Y, X, 3))
coords_ext[...,[1,0]] = np.rollaxis(np.indices((Y, X)), 0, start=3)
coords_ext[...,2] = 1

# convert to column vectors and back for matmul broadcasting
result = (matrix @ coords_ext[...,None])[...,0]

# or alternatively, work with row vectors and do it in the other order
result = coords_ext @ matrix.T
```

Comment: Had to make few changes to your posted code to match up the output values with the OP's double loop approach as needed for value verification under the runtime test.  Hope they look okay.

Comment: @Divakar: How do my fixes look?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Updated the profiling tests. Some improvement there on the timings with these fixes!