# Python3 / Numpy: ndarray conditional indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I'm coming from a MATLAB background and I'm trying to write this in python/numpy:

```
[l, m, n] = ndgrid(1:size(dct, 1), 1:size(dct, 2), 1:size(dct, 3));
mycell{i, j} = dct(...
    min.^2 <= l.^2 + m.^2 + n.^2 & ...
    l.^2 + m.^2 + n.^2 <= max.^2)';
```

So what the code is supposed to to is take all the values of the array that have an index (e.g. x,y,z) that have a 2-norm between `min` and `max`, i.e. `min^2 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < max^2`

The only thing I could find was about indexing some values of an array with a condition of the value of the array at this index, however I want to index with a condition on the index itself.

I read about broadcasting and the `ix_` function and advanced indexing, however i cannot fit the pieces together.

Comment: @Divakar made an edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: As a good practice, it would be nice to avoid names like `min`, `max` that are already names for builtins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NumPy offers us to create open meshes, which could replace the 3D meshes with the help of [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html). This would essentially replace the `ndgrid` part from MATLAB code, but with additional benefits (read on for more details). These meshes could then be squared and added to perform the equivalent of `l.^2 + m.^2 + n.^2` without actually creating `3D` versions of `l`, `m` and `n` as we had done with `ndgrid`. This is a huge performance criteria and has been explored in [`this previous post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667342/3293881) and it has shown performance benefits.

Thus, porting over to NumPy, we would have -

```
m,n,r = dct.shape    
x,y,z = np.ogrid[0:m,0:n,0:r]
vals = x**2+y**2+z**2
mycell[i][j] = dct[(min**2 <= vals) & (vals <= max**2)]
```