# Find neighbors with cuts efficiently and return index

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, nearest-neighbor

I have many points in the `x,y` plane, with length around 10000, each point `(x,y)` has an intrinsic radius `r`. This small data set is only one tiny corner of my entire data set. I have an interested point `(x1,y1)`, I want to find nearby point around `(x1,y1)` within 1 and meet the criteria that the distance between `(x,y)` and `(x1,y1)` is less than `r`. I want to return the index of those good points, not the good points themselves.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2000)
x = 20.*np.random.rand(10000)
y = 20.*np.random.rand(10000)
r = 0.3*np.random.rand(10000)
x1 = 10.  ### (x1,y1) is an interest point 
y1 = 12.
def index_finder(x,y,r,x1,y1):
    idx = (abs(x - x1) < 1.) & (abs(y - y1) < 1.)  ### This cut will probably cut 90% of the data
    x_temp = x[idx]   ### but if I do like this, then I lose the track of the original index
    y_temp = y[idx]
    dis_square = (x_temp - x1)*(x_temp - x1) + (y_temp - y1)*(y_temp - y1)
    idx1 = dis_square < r*r    ### after this cut, there are only a few left 
    x_good = x_temp[idx1]
    y_good = y_temp[idx1]
```

In this function, I can find the good points around `(x1,y1)`, but not the index of those good points. HOWEVER, I need the ORIGINAL index because the ORIGINAL index are used to extract other data associated with the coordinate `(x,y)`. As I mentioned, the sample data set is only a tiny corner of my entire data set, I will call the above function around 1,000,000 times for my entire data set, therefore the efficiency of the above `index_finder` function is also a consideration.

Any thoughts on such task?

Comment: How are using `index_finder` for all those points? Are you using it in a loop or just like that?

Comment: I will use this function inside a loop Because I have many such interested point like `(x1,y1)`. This function itself can avoid any loop. And this data set is only 1/1000 of my whole data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could simply index into the first mask with its own mask for selecting the True places masked values from the second stage, like so -

```
idx[idx] = idx1
```

Thus, `idx` would have the final valid masked values/ good valued places corresponding to original array `x` and `y`, i.e. -

```
x_good = x[idx]
y_good = y[idx]
```

This mask could then be used to index into other arrays as mentioned in the question.

---

**Approach #2**

As another approach, we could use two conditional statements , thus creating two masks with them. Finally, combine them with `AND-ing` to get the combined mask, which could be indexed into `x` and `y` arrays for the final outputs. We won't need to get the actual indices that way, so that's one more benefit with it.

Hence, the implementation -

```
X = x-x1
Y = y-y1
mask1 = (np.abs(X) < 1.) & (np.abs(Y) < 1.)
mask2 = X**2 + Y*2 < r**2
comb_mask = mask1 & mask2

x_good = x[comb_mask]
y_good = y[comb_mask]
```

If for some reason, you still need the corresponding indices, just do -

```
comb_idx = np.flatnonzero(comb_mask)
```

If you are doing these operations for different `x1` and `y1` pairs for the same `x` and `y` dataset, I would suggest using `broadcasting` to vectorize it through all those `x1`, `y1` paired datasets, as shown in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667342/3293881).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this implementation will be a little bit less efficient. I also want to speed it up because I will have a large loop around 1,000,000 times to call this function.

Comment: @HuanianZhang Little bit less efficient than what?

Comment: I guess it will be a little less efficient than my implementation. Because it only calculates about 10% of the data in the second cut. But the drawback of my implementation is that it can not return index.

Comment: In order to speed it up (because I have 1 million loops), then I split the two cuts. I will test your implementation to see how long it will take.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I tried your two approaches. Interesting, the second approach is more efficient. I have the resutls and time usage for both like below: `[1575 3709 5706]
time used   for approach 1  is 0.000797033309937
[1575 3709 5706]
time used   for approach 2 is  0.000538110733032`. That is totally unexpected.

Comment: @HuanianZhang It's probably the indexing : `x[idx]` that's killing the first one. Also, we could use `power` instead of self-multiplication, updated.

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where)  seems made for finding the indices

the vectorized norm calc + `np.where()` could be faster than a loop

```
sq_norm = (x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2  # no need to take 10000 sqrt
idcs = np.where(sq_norm < 1.)

len(idcs[0])
Out[193]: 69

np.stack((idcs[0], x[idcs], y[idcs]), axis=1)[:5]
Out[194]: 
array([[  38.        ,    9.47165956,   11.94250173],
       [  39.        ,    9.6966941 ,   11.67505453],
       [ 276.        ,   10.68835317,   12.11589316],
       [ 288.        ,    9.93632584,   11.07624915],
       [ 344.        ,    9.48644057,   12.04911857]])
```

the norm calc can include the `r` array too, the 2nd step?

```
r_sq_norm = (x[idcs] - x1)**2 + (y[idcs] - y1)**2 - r[idcs]**2
r_idcs = np.where(r_sq_norm < 0.)

idcs[0][r_idcs]
Out[11]: array([1575, 3476, 3709], dtype=int64)
```

you might want to time the 2 step test vs including `r` in the 1st vectorized norm calc?

```
sq_norm = (x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2 - r**2
idcs = np.where(sq_norm < 0.)

idcs[0]
Out[13]: array([1575, 3476, 3709], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a mask of your indices, like so:

```
def index_finder(x,y,r,x1,y1):
    idx = np.nonzero((abs(x - x1) < 1.) & (abs(y - y1) < 1.))  #numerical, not boolean
    mask = (x[idx] - x1)*(x[idx] - x1) + (y[idx] - y1)*(y[idx] - y1) < r*r
    idx1 = [i[mask] for i in idx]
    x_good = x_temp[idx1]
    y_good = y_temp[idx1]
```

now `idx1` is the indices you want to extract.

Faster way in general to do this is to use `scipy.spatial.KDTree`

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

xy = np.stack((x,y))
kdt = KDTree(xy)
kdt.query_ball_point([x1, y1], r)
```

If you have many points to query against the same dataset, this will be *much* faster than sequentially calling your `index_finder` app.

```
x1y1 = np.stack((x1, y1)) #`x1` and `y1` are arrays of coordinates.
kdt.query_ball_point(x1y1, r)
```

**ALSO WRONG:** if you have different distances for each point, you can do:

```
def query_variable_ball(kdtree, x, y, r):
    out = []
    for x_, y_, r_ in zip(x, y, r):
        out.append(kdt.query_ball_point([x_, y_], r_)
    return out

xy = np.stack((x,y))
kdt = KDTree(xy)
query_variable_ball(kdt, x1, y1, r)
```

**EDIT 2:**  This should work with different `r` values for each point

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

def index_finder_kd(x, y, r, x1, y1):  # all arrays
    xy = np.stack((x,y), axis = -1)
    x1y1 = np.stack((x1, y1), axis = -1)
    xytree = KDTree(xy)
    d, i = xytree.query(x1y1, k = None, distance_upper_bound = 1.)
    good_idx = np.zeros(x.size, dtype = bool)
    for idx, dist in zip(i, d):
        good_idx[idx] |= r[idx] > dist
    x_good = x[good_idx]
    y_good = y[good_idx]
    return x_good, y_good, np.flatnonzero(good_idx)
```

This is *very* slow for only one `(x1, y1)` pair as the `KDTree` takes a while to populate.  But if you have millions of pairs, this will be much faster.

(I've assumed you want the union of all good points in the `(x, y)` data for all `(x1, y1)`, if you want them separately it's also possible using a similar method, removing elements of `i[j]` based on whether `d[j] < r[i[j]]`)

Comment: Isn't `index_finder #2` same as what I am suggesting in my post at the start?

Comment: Yes.  Didn't notice because I jumped straight to Approach #2.

Comment: If it doesn't sound too offensive, would you remove that part? Two posts with same content doesn't look too good :)

Comment: Not sure why if we're going for complete answers, but ok.

Comment: Appreciate it .

Comment: It seems the `KDTree` is not working properly. Because here `r` is an array not a number.  But thanks.

Comment: Wait, that's wrong.  How many `(x1, y1)` pairs are you planning to call?